# How can I add the Komodo chess engine to ChessBase 9?

Tags: engines, chessbase

I bought the Komodo 10 chess engine.

Nowhere in the instructions that I could find does it explain how to add it as an engine, nor can I find any "komodo.eng" file in the Komodo directories.

What happens when try to add Komodo as a UCI engine. First this screen appears as I open "ChessEngine15.exe" in the Komodo directory:

[image]

Notice how the "OK" button is grayed out. Then after I click "Open" this happens:

[image]

The screen stays like this for about 20 seconds, then the Komodo front page disappears and the "Loading ChessProgram15.exe" box disappears as well, but the "Set up UCI Engine" dialog remains the same with the OK button grayed out, so there is no way to proceed other than Cancel. Clicking the "Parameters" button results in a "Loading" box, followed by a dialog box "Doesn't have parameters":

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the main exe is not the engine. The engine EXE is kind of hidden.

I was able to find the engine by using the SysInternals tool "Process Explorer". By starting Komodo and running Process Explorer I found that the main Komodo program launches the engine EXE as a child process.

The location of this child process on my Windows XP machine was the following:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\ChessBase\Engines.uci\Komodo 10\

By browsing to the exe in this folder in the UCI engine selection shown in the question, it worked.